# Выдает ошибку в коде для телеграмм бота TypeError: Updater.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_context'

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, бот, анализ

Вот весь код:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

def analyze_sentiment(update, context):
    text = update.message.text
    scores = sid.polarity_scores(text)
    compound_score = scores['compound']

    if compound_score < 0:
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Ваше сообщение было определено как негативное. Вы заблокированы.")
        context.bot.kick_chat_member(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, user_id=update.message.from_user.id)

updater = Updater("OKEN", use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.text & ~filters.command, analyze_sentiment))

updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.